# ASP.MVC :Web.Config and Authorize attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have an AdminController protected by an Authorize attribute like this

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class AdminController :  BaseController
{
.....
}
```

And I have in my web.config this security location section

```
<location path="admin">
   <system.webServer>
       <security>
          <authorization>
            <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
            <add accessType="Allow" roles="Admin" />
          </authorization>
       </security>
   </system.webServer>
</location>
```

If I remove the web config section, everything works perfectly and only Admin can access Admin actions
With the section in, I am always redirected to my login page

However, I need the web.config section because I have some static files on the Admin folder  that I want to be protected and accessed only by Admin role

What's wrong with my web.config
Thanks

Comment: unless a new syntax came out and I'm unaware, the correct tag is <deny> instead of <remove>...

Answer (score 1):

easiest way is to add a new web config file to the admin section

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>     
        <authorization>
          <deny users="*" />
          <allow roles="Admin" />   
       </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```